# How draw 3 lines sequentially on visual studio using timer?

Tags: c#, draw

I want this simple demo program to draw 3 lines at intervals of 500 msec between them [(i.e. draw line one (pause interval 500msec), draw line two (pause interval 500msec), draw line 3 and finally stop timer1].

I have already entered the value 500msec in the corresponting (timer1 property Behavior Interval) field on visual studio. As it is now, the demo program does draw the three lines, but the interval of 500 msec does not work (obviously because there is code missing in void timer1_Tick.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp44

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Graphics g;
    Pen p;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        g = this.CreateGraphics();
        p = new Pen(Color.Red, 5);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
        g.DrawLine(p, 200, 200, 300, 100);
        g.DrawLine(p, 300, 100, 400, 200);
        g.DrawLine(p, 200, 200, 400, 200);
        timer1.Stop();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: You basically need to draw the line in the Tick event. Also do a check to see how many lines you have drawn and call Stop after 3

Comment: Thanks for the tip. II have tried that also (ie the 3 draw lines in the Tick event, but still performs them all at once, and no intervals occur).

Comment: you need to count the lines and draw the appropriate line. Somebody has posted an answer with the same logic I was suggesting anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp13
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Graphics g;
        Pen p;
        int tickcount = 1;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            g = this.CreateGraphics();
            p = new Pen(Color.Red, 5);
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch (tickcount)
            {
                case 1:
                    g.DrawLine(p, 200, 200, 300, 100);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    g.DrawLine(p, 300, 100, 400, 200);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    g.DrawLine(p, 200, 200, 400, 200);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            tickcount++;
            if (tickcount > 3)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                timer1.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Enabled = true` and `Start()` do the same thing, no need to use both. Same applies of `false` and `Stop()`

Comment: @musefan You are right. Thanks for the help! It works fine now!

Comment: @arch1 You should avoid CreateGraphics.  It's a temporary buffer that can be erased.  Always use the graphic provided by a container's paint event.